# Impulse Response in Z - Domain of a Transfer Function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, response

I am implementing Z-Domain TF on MATLAB. While plotting the Pole-Zero Plot, I find that it is correct, and I have no problem in that. The problem is when I plot the Impulse response; i.e `h(n)`; I find that the first delta is always shifted by one, thus all the other deltas are also shifted. Why does the shift happen? Does anybody have any idea about this problem?

I have provided a simple example of many I have already implemented.

```
close all;clear;clc;

Ts = 0.1;

num = 1; % b
den = 1; % a

hz = tf(num, den, Ts, 'variable', 'z^-1')

%% Plotting
figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
pzplot(hz)
axis equal

subplot(2,1,2)
stem(impulse(hz*Ts))
axis([0 10 0 1.1])
grid minor
```

[image: impulse response]

Comment: It might be `stem` plotting "issue". If you do just do `stem(1:10)` the 'x-axis' will start from `1` rather than `0`. I do not have some of the toolboxes so i can not test the and verify.

Comment: @mpaskov Actually I am letting MATLAB to plot with its dummy axis. I did this in many other implementation, but when I try it in this example, the deltas are shifted to right by one. !!!

Comment: Exactly the matlab's dummy axis starts at `1` that is the first value of the impulse, is that not what you are expecting?

Comment: @mpaskov Yes, I am not expecting this shift. I have tried to plot many other examples using `syms`, and the shift does not happen, although I used the dummy axis in the `syms` examples. That's what I don't get.

Comment: If you do `stem(0:length(hz)-1,impulse(hz*Ts))`, how does that look?

Comment: In fact, your time axis should be something like `(0:N-1)/N*Ts`. As pointed out above, if you pass none to stem, it uses `1:N`. This does not make any sense physically though, since the first sample corresponds to t=0 and samples have a spacing of `Ts`.

Comment: @Florian Where N indicates what ?

Comment: @mpaskov I tried your answer in the comments here, but it is always giving me this error `X must be same length as Y`. I am unable to determine the length(hz). It is always 1 in any case of any number of coefficients in the num or den

Comment: @OsamaAbbas: try `length(impulse(hz*Ts))`. That's what I meant by `N`. Though the x-axis should be `(0:N-1)*Ts` (not /N).

Comment: Ohh i think `hz` might a matlab structure or something like that: try then `temp = impulse(hz*Ts); stem(0:length(temp)-1,temp)`, just to make sure you are getting what you want, I am sure there is a better way of going about it.

Comment: @mpaskov Actually this works well. Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: @Florian Thanks a lot, you really helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the plotting rather than the results. If you do not specify the value for the 'x-axis' matlab will create a dummy variable which start from `1` and end with the length of the vector, essentially `1:length(y)`. You should create your own x-vector (and scale it as suggested by @Florian):

```
response = impulse(hz*Ts);
timevector = (0:length(response)-1)*Ts;
stem(timevector,reponse);
grid minor;
```